# How to show art in terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I want to the Ubuntu terminal to show art like this picture:

[image: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-X9_7lpr3y_I/Tz5xkBHO-BI/AAAAAAAAAWo/OWF11KTnPNA/s320/msfconsole.png]

How to do that? I want put my own logo using the word character.
I would like to arrange it and form a logo.

Please teach me the way..

Comment: If it is correct that OP wishes to have a custom image as background for the terminal,the answer may be here: http://askubuntu.com/a/225828/25656 and the current question maybe a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/107444/25656

Comment: @vasa1, He is asking about showing ASCII graphics like stuff on terminal launch.

Comment: I'm not sure; there appear to be gradient effects present ... see the blue horizontal rectangles. Anyway, it's a pretty poorly worded question. I tried to edit it but gave up.

Comment: @vasa1, I agree taht the question is poorly worded. :)

Answer (score 6):

**Easiest method:**
Use `fortune` and `cowsay`.

- Install fortune and cowsay:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install fortune cowsay
  ```
- At the end of `.bashrc` file in your Home directory add the following line:

  ```
  fortune | cowsay -f tux
  ```

**Courtesy:** http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/886

**Sample Output:**

```
 _________________________________________
/ Your aims are high, and you are capable \
\ of much.                                /
 -----------------------------------------
   \
    \
        .--.
       |o_o |
       |:_/ |
      //   \ \
     (|     | )
    /'\_   _/`\
    \___)=(___/

saji@geeklap:~$
```

**Another method:**
Get a good ASCII art from some site(or you can create on your own), create a new file in your home directory, paste the ASCII art in that file(as it is). Let  us save the file as `asciiart` for now ( you can use any other name you like, just remember to use that name in the `.bashrc` file). In the `.bashrc` file, put the last line as:

```
cat acsiiart
```

**Base idea from:** http://dorkbyte.com/2012/08/05/trick-out-your-terminal-with-ascii-art/

Comment: thanx @saji89 ...

Comment: @kiriya19, You can mark the answer as accepted, if it helped you, so that the question will be marked solved.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you can manipulate the terminal display using special character sequences. You can find useful lists of the special commands the terminal understands [here](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) or [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c327.html). Note that these commands are not being interpreted by the shell (eg, `bash`), but by the terminal emulator (eg `gnome-terminal`, `xterm`, etc).

(To further complicate matters, there are different types of terminal which can be emulated. The above character sequences apply to an emulated [VT100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) terminal, which is probably a safe bet. These different types of terminals now emulated in software correspond to physical terminals which could be connected to Unix mainframes of lore.)

All special commands start with an escape character, after which the terminal interprets the next few characters.

To change the text colour to blue, for example

```
$ echo -e "\033[34mhello blue world\033[0m"
```

`\033` is the code for the `ESCAPE` character, which starts the sequence. `[34m` sets the text attribute `34`, which is foreground colour blue. The text `hello blue world` is then echoed as normal, except that the attributes currently used for printing have changed (to blue text), and finally the escape sequence and command `[0m` returns text printing to normal. (`echo -e` ensures the sequence `\033` is interpreted as a character code and not the four characters `\ 0 3 3`).

Attempting to do anything complex using these commands manually will very quickly give you a headache.

The [`curses`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) library provides an abstraction layer for making user interfaces on a terminal. The [python binding](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) is probably a good place to start if you want to try it out - but be warned, the library is pretty arcane and the documentation doubly so.

For the case of trying to output graphics, the correct tool is probably [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca).